# How to set an evenHandler in WPF to all windows (entire application)?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, keydown

How can I set an event handler (such as `keydown`) to entire solution, not a single window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Register a global event handler in your application class (App.cs), like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.KeyDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Window_KeyDown));
    }

    void Window_KeyDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

This will handle the `KeyDown` event for any `Window` in your app. You can cast `e` to `KeyEventArgs` to get to the information about the pressed key.

Comment: thanks this is the direction, i saw this once , it had something with register handler and stuff. ill try this and report

Comment: actually instead of casting you can just replace `new RoutedEventHandler(..)` with `new KeyEventHandler(Window_KeyDown)`

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
 public partial class App : Application {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.KeyDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(KeyDown));
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }

        void KeyDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a delegate, to connect the event(wherever it is) and the function your willing to work when the event jumps.

you can load as many events as you want to your delegate.

mzE.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `KeyDown` will work only in the current window, because you need focus for `KeyDown`. What you can do is add a handler to all windows and dispatch another event in those handlers, then register all classes that you need with this new event.

alternatively, have a look at the `Observer` pattern

Comment: I once made that happen... I dont remember how i copied it fro, somewhere I cant find now

Answer (score 0):

Either you register the event in all windows and pass it on to a global function/event or (in  case of the keydown or similar) you use some global "event catching" (like [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook) for the keyboard).

Comment: I once made that happen... I dont remember how i copied it fro, somewhere I cant find now